# Sacar datos de un observable (subscriber) en angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, filtro

primero lo que deseo hacer o intento hacer es utilizar una barra de menu con opciones y usar los valores para filtrar dependiendo de dicho valor, entonces como lo hago..

componente 1 aca esta la barra de menu, componente 2 listado que deseo filtrar, utilizo un service para la comunicacion entre los componentes y funciona bien, el problema radica en que el dato que intento obtener del componente 1 me sale undefine fuera de la funcion de subscribe y no la puedo usar para filtrar el listado.

```
    this.communicationService.communication$.subscribe( (data) => {
data === this.x; 
console.log(data) // arroja los datos esperados.
});
```

asi es como obtengo los datos del componente 1, ahora bien cuando doy console log a los datos perfecto ahi comunicacion entre los componente y todo pero cuando quiero utilizar this.x para filtrar los datos this.x sale undefined.

cuando intento hacer esto no me tira ningun dato.

```
this.resultado = this.listadoAFiltrar.filter( (f) => {
  return f.opcion === this.x 
});
```

e incluso he intentado hacer esto pero sin resultado

```
this.communicationService.communication$.subcribe( data => {
   this.resultado = this.listadoAFiltrar.filter( f => {
     return f.opcion === data;
   })
})
```

alguna ayuda con esto por favor, gracias por la ayuda que puedan darme para poder resolver este problema. bien, ahora el da

Answer (score 1):

en el subscribe estas haciendo `data === this.x;`, debes escribir `this.x = data;`  this.x te da undefined porque nunca le asignas el valor de `data`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.communicationService.communication$.subcribe( data => {
   this.resultado = this.listadoAFiltrar.filter( f => {
     return f.opcion === data;
   });
// Aquí debes trabajar con lo que se guarde en this.resultado
});
```

Si llamas a `this.resultado` afuera del subscribe todavía no tendrá valor porque subscribe es asíncrono.

Quiere decir que cuando subscribe es llamado empieza a procesar los datos en segundo plano y cuando los datos están listos ejecuta la función anónima que se le ha pasado al método y le pasa los datos en la variable `data`. A todo esto el código después del subscribe se sigue ejecutando y por esa razón `this.resultado` está vacio afuera del `subscribe()`, porque sus datos aún no están listos.

Comment: Gracias pero no funciona, el this.resultado esta al mismo nivel que el subscriber del que ya esta, lo que quiero es poder imprimir los resultados en pantalla y actualmente no obtengo nada. O tenes alguna otra opcion para poder lograrlo.. ejemplo cuando hago el ngfor el array da undefined/vacio y por consola obtengo todos los resultados tal como deseo.  @crrlos

Comment: Para aclarar, cuando imprimes this.resultado por consola puedes ver los datos que tiene?

Comment: si cuando los imprimo por consolo todo esta super, veo los resultados, todo esta perfecto en ese punto. pero al tratar de pasarlo por pantalla nada..

Comment: Agrega el código que usas para mostrarlos en pantalla